# Getting syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This was working until 5 minutes ago and I'm not sure what I edited that screwed things up. I've rolled back to the version I had before and I'm still getting the error. I've gone line by line to make sure I don't have an extra end and unless I'm blind, each `end` matches up with a `def`.

Specific Error:
`SyntaxError in CompaniesController#index
/projects/TSO/app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:93: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input`

Here's my code:

```
    class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_contact!, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /companies
  # GET /companies.json
  def index
   @company = Company.find(@company.id, include: :contacts, include: :subscriptions)
  end

  # GET /companies/1
  # GET /companies/1.json
  def show

    @company = Company.find(@company.id, include: :contacts, include: :subscriptions)

  end

  # GET /companies/new
  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @company.contacts.build

  end

  # GET /companies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /companies
  # POST /companies.json
  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
         sign_in(@company.contacts.first)

        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /companies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /companies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.update(company_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /companies/1
  # DELETE /companies/1.json
  def destroy
    @company.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to companies_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_company
      if params[:id].nil?
        @company = Company.find(current_contact.company_id)
      else
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])
      end
    end


    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :legal_entity, :KVK_number, :VAT_number, contacts_attributes:[:first_name, :last_name, :address, :phone, :email, :postcode, :password] )
    end
  end
end
```

No idea on what I'm doing wrong now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is messed up and you've added an extra `end` in there because of it.

The `private` declaration should be at the same level as `class`.

A general template looks like:

```
class Example
  def method
    # ...
  end

private
  def private_method
  end
end
```

What you have:

```
class Example
  def method
    # ...
  end

  private
    def private_method
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - this was part of the problem, but figured out the real root cause was in the subscription.rb model where I had added a new method, but messed up the end. In order to fix the problem I removed the extra end in the controller and then got the next end error when I called the subscription model. So anything in the company controller that required the subscription model was causing the error. After fixing the model all works